# How to change text mode to password mode after entering in textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form in ASP.NET as below :-

```
Number(textbox)
Name(textbox)
Age(textbox)
sex(textbox)
Marks(textbox)
Class(textbox)
Re enter number(textbox)
Save(button)
```

In this fields after entering number, when I go for next field number filed of textbox data of text mode should convert to password mode. after entering "re enter number" it should check for matching both "number" and "re enter number" and should display message like number is matched or not matched and then save data.

Please it is urgent.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set the textmode of the textbox to Password.

Like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: but at runtime it should display the text when we goto next field it should convert to password mode.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to do some javascript here,

```
txt1.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.type='text';");
txt1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "this.type='password';");
```

Alternativly you could do the same with jQuery (and a bit more clean) but setting a CSS Class to the objects you want to do the switching with and then add a

```
$(".hideContentOnBlur").blur(function() {
  this.type='password';
});

$(".hideContentOnBlur").focus(function() {
  this.type='text';
});
```